# Decrypt AES encrypted string in Node.JS with no IV

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption

I've been working on decrypting a few strings, and I've gotten them decrypted in Ruby (that's where they were originally encrypted). In Ruby, this is the method I'm calling to decrypt:

Using https://rubygems.org/gems/aes

```
def decrypt(str)
  AES.decrypt(str, ENV["AES_KEY"])
end
```

In Node, this is what I've tried:

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(secret, key);
const decryptedMessage = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

But no luck using that — my result is always equal to an empty String. I'm probably missing something very small or stupid, but any suggestions or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: We cannot provide you with a guide without seeing the Ruby code!

Comment: @kelalaka I expanded upon the snippet I provided previously.

Comment: The Ruby library uses AES-256 by default, i.e. a 32 bytes (64 hex digits) key must be used. Shorter keys are implicitly padded with 0x00 values. So that decryption with CryptoJS is possible, shorter keys must be explicitly padded to 32 bytes accordingly in CryptoJS. In principle the Ruby library also allows other AES variants (AES-128, AES-192), but this is currently not possible due to a bug, s. [issue #17](https://github.com/chicks/aes/issues/17)!

Answer (score 3):

The key in the [Ruby code](https://github.com/chicks/aes/blob/master/lib/aes/aes.rb) is the hexadecimal encoding of the bytes, so you need to decode it first. Then you should not use the `decrypt` mode that just uses the `secret` and `key` parameters but also specify the key and IV as `WordArray`:

> For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV. *Or you can pass a `WordArray` that represents the actual key. If you pass the actual key, you must also pass the actual IV*.

Now the IV is prefixed to the ciphertext as base 64, separated by a dollar sign.

The ciphertext is also base 64 encoded, so you need to decode that first too. There are encoder functions in the library to help you with that:

So in the end you should be doing something similar to this:

```js
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext),                  
    CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyHex),
    { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ivHex) }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: This is really helpful — thank you! The only thing I'm confused about is how to derive    the ivHex — as I said before there's no IV specified when encrypting in Ruby. It's possible that I'm just misunderstanding you, so apologies if that's the case. Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` expects a `CipherParams` object as 1st parameter (not a `WordArray`), e.g. `{ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext)}`. Alternatively, the ciphertext can be passed Base64 encoded: `ciphertext`, which will be converted to a `CipherParams` object under the hood.

Comment: The IV is prefixed to the ciphertext, check the code link I have included in the answer, it clearly shows the process and is not hard to read at all; the actual AES encryption is separate.